# Ordering a string with multiple dots in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array:

```
["4.1.0.57", "4.1.0.99", "4.1.0.54", "4.1.0.65", "4.1.0.87", "4.1.0.97", "4.1.0.63", "4.1.0.96", "4.1.0.51", "4.1.0.84", "4.1.0.95", "4.1.0.105", "4.1.0.38", "4.1.0.59", "4.1.0.47", "4.1.0.69", "4.1.0.93", "4.1.0.92", "4.1.0.103", "4.1.0.100", "4.1.0.90"]
```

I am trying to sort this using lodash:

```
_.sortBy(keys)
_.orderBy(keys)
```

`["4.1.0.100", "4.1.0.103", "4.1.0.105", "4.1.0.38", "4.1.0.47", "4.1.0.51", "4.1.0.54", "4.1.0.57", "4.1.0.59", "4.1.0.63", "4.1.0.65", "4.1.0.69", "4.1.0.84", "4.1.0.87", "4.1.0.90", "4.1.0.92", "4.1.0.93", "4.1.0.95", "4.1.0.96", "4.1.0.97", "4.1.0.99"]`

Its not ordering properly

Comment: by what should it be ordered?

Answer (score 6):

You could sort with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and options.

```js
var array = ["4.1.0.57", "4.1.0.99", "4.1.0.54", "4.1.0.65", "4.1.0.87", "4.1.0.97", "4.1.0.63", "4.1.0.96", "4.1.0.51", "4.1.0.84", "4.1.0.95", "4.1.0.105", "4.1.0.38", "4.1.0.59", "4.1.0.47", "4.1.0.69", "4.1.0.93", "4.1.0.92", "4.1.0.103", "4.1.0.100", "4.1.0.90"];

array.sort(function (a,b) {
 return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```